# how to tighten a PCB inside this box?

Tags: pcb-design

I've bought this box for my PCB. There are several holes on it, but the holes are closed at one end. How can I design my PCB to be fixed in this box? Should I add hole for screws on my PCB? I can puncture the box, but it won't look good!

I don't know the application of these holes.

[image: box]

Comment: Use screws which are not too long.

Comment: Given they are square holes, I presume they are designed for some form of push fit captive nut. Or just some self tapping screws.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect the documentation for the box to specify a screw size that would cut its own threads in those holes (the box might even come with appropriate screws).

You would place holes in your PC board to match the post positions in the box.

Comment: Do you mean that these square holes are for self tapping screws?

Comment: They may be intended for self-tapping screws, but the plastic is probably soft enough that normal screws will work.

Answer (score 1):

Design your PCBs to fit into the box.
[image]

Comment: This isn't what the OP was asking, he was asking how to secure the PCB inside the box, not how to fit it around the screw holes.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I don't think so, he does not asked how to secure.

Comment: "How can I design my PCB to be **fixed** in this box?". "Fixed" means "secured"

Comment: @DerStrom8 You're true. I meant how to "secure" the board. Also, it is simpler to put holes on the board rather than changing the board shape from its rectangular form.